# compiler error in class with datamember of type typedef map<std::string,std::pair<std::string,vector<int>>> MapPairList;?

Tags: c++, data-structures, compiler-errors

Here is my code.

class xyz.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

typedef map<std::string,std::pair<std::string,vector<int>>> MapPairList;

class xyz
{
private:
    MapPairList m1;

public:
    void insert();
    string GetType(string& filetype);
    vector<int> GetExtList(string& filetype);
};
```

Implementation of above class.

```
    #include "xyz.h"

void xyz::insert()
{
    vector<int> v1;
    v1.push_back(1);
    v1.push_back(2);
    v1.push_back(3);

    vector<int> v2;
    v2.push_back(1);
    v2.push_back(2);
    v2.push_back(3);

    vector<int> v3;
    v3.push_back(1);
    v3.push_back(2);
    v3.push_back(3);

    string c1 = "type1";
    string f1 ="filetype1";
    string c2 = "type2";
    string f2 ="filetype2";
    string c3 = "type3";
    string f3 ="filetype3";

    m1.insert(make_pair(f1,make_pair(c1,v1)));
    m1.insert(make_pair(f2,make_pair(c2,v2)));
    m1.insert(make_pair(f3,make_pair(c3,v3)));
}

string xyz::GetType(std::string &filetype)
{
    MapPairList::iterator iter = m1.find(filetype);

    if(iter != m1.end())
    {
        return (*iter).second.first;
    }
}

vector<int> xyz::GetExtList(std::string &filetype)
{
    MapPairList::iterator iter = m1.find(filetype);

    if(iter != m1.end())
        return (*iter).second.second;
}

int main()
{
    xyz *x = new xyz();

    string out("filetype1");
    string in = x->GetType(out);
    cout<<in.c_str();

    delete x;
    return 0;
}
```

And when I try to compile I get following errors:

```
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\functional(143) : error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Tree<_Traits> &,const std::_Tree<_Traits> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Tree<_Traits> &' from 'const std::string'
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xtree(1372) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\functional(142) : while compiling class template member function 'bool std::less<_Ty>::operator ()(const _Ty &,const _Ty &) const'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=std::string
1>        ]
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\map(72) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::less<_Ty>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=std::string
1>        ]
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xtree(26) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,_Mfl>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=std::string,
1>            _Ty=std::pair<std::string,std::vector<int>>,
1>            _Pr=std::less<std::string>,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,std::pair<std::string,std::vector<int>>>>,
1>            _Mfl=false
1>        ]
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xtree(68) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree_nod<_Traits>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<std::string,std::pair<std::string,std::vector<int>>,std::less<std::string>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,std::pair<std::string,std::vector<int>>>>,false>
1>        ]
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xtree(94) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree_ptr<_Traits>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<std::string,std::pair<std::string,std::vector<int>>,std::less<std::string>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,std::pair<std::string,std::vector<int>>>>,false>
1>        ]
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xtree(112) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree_val<_Traits>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<std::string,std::pair<std::string,std::vector<int>>,std::less<std::string>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,std::pair<std::string,std::vector<int>>>>,false>
1>        ]
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\map(82) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree<_Traits>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<std::string,std::pair<std::string,std::vector<int>>,std::less<std::string>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,std::pair<std::string,std::vector<int>>>>,false>
1>        ]
1>        c:\documents and settings\apoos\my documents\visual studio 2005\projects\algos\maplistpair\xyz.h(12) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=std::string,
1>            _Ty=std::pair<std::string,std::vector<int>>
1>        ]
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\functional(143) : error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Tree<_Traits> &,const std::_Tree<_Traits> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Tree<_Traits> &' from 'const std::string'
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xtree(1372) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\functional(143) : error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Tree<_Traits> &,const std::_Tree<_Traits> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Tree<_Traits> &' from 'const std::string'
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xtree(1372) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\functional(143) : error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Tree<_Traits> &,const std::_Tree<_Traits> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Tree<_Traits> &' from 'const std::string'
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xtree(1372) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\functional(143) : error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &,const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &' from 'const std::string'
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\vector(1276) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\functional(143) : error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &,const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &' from 'const std::string'
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\vector(1276) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\functional(143) : error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &,const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &' from 'const std::string'
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\vector(1276) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\functional(143) : error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &,const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &' from 'const std::string'
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\vector(1276) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\functional(143) : error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'const std::string'
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xutility(1880) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\functional(143) : error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'const std::string'
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xutility(1880) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\functional(143) : error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'const std::string'
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xutility(1880) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\functional(143) : error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'const std::string'
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xutility(1880) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\functional(143) : error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &,const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &' from 'const std::string'
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\utility(76) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\functional(143) : error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &,const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &' from 'const std::string'
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\utility(76) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\functional(143) : error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &,const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &' from 'const std::string'
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\utility(76) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\functional(143) : error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &,const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &' from 'const std::string'
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\utility(76) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\functional(143) : error C2676: binary '<' : 'const std::string' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
```

Actually I am trying to use only the specific data structure.

If you have a better solution to replace this data structure with other one please suggest that. Mapping of element is container is one to one between 1st two string. And one to many between the element in the pair.That is why last element in the pair is a vector.
Can any one tell me what went wrong?

Comment: ">>>" only works in C++11. Pre-C++11 requires "> > >".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

g++ says   `error: ‘>>’ should be ‘> >’ within a nested template argument list`

Change your `typedef` to:

```
typedef map<std::string,std::pair<std::string,vector<int> > > MapPairList;
```

Comment: After making this change also I am getting following error. Is it compiling for you after making this change.

Comment: @user904729 `g++` will `#include <string>` default. In msvc++, you should include manually.

Comment: I have included String "#include<string>" but now it is crashing, following is the call stack

Comment: You forgot to call `x->insert();`

Comment: @kev: I have never heard about g++ including anything by default ?!

Answer (score 3):

You have not included `<string>`. Add `#include <string>` before `typedef...`.